# Getting the inputted values in the array by passing a function

Tags: c#, oop

I am having some troubles in getting the inputted values in my array. We are required to create a function for the "methods". Let me explain it further.

Here's the full block of my code:

```
using System;
class LabExer
{

  static void arrayVal(string[] arr)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(arr[i] + ": ");
            arr[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            
        }
  }

  static void Method1(){
      //Console.Write(letters[i]);
  }
  
  static void Main ()
  {
    string[] letters = {"S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};
    int choice = 0;
    while (choice!=5)
    {
        
        Console.WriteLine("Hello! Enter values, then choose your action below:");
        arrayVal(letters);
        
        Console.WriteLine("\n1. Method 1");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Method 2");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Method 3");
        Console.WriteLine("4. Method 4");
        Console.WriteLine("5. Exit");
        
        choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                Method1();
        }
    }
    
  }
}
```

For Method 1:

I am trying to get the user inputted values from `arrayVal` by calling it in `letters[i]` but it gives me an error that it doesn't exist in context. For the meantime, I am just trying to print out the values using a function as it may help me figure out what to do. Unfortunately I still can't.

Any suggestions will be a great help.

Comment: You need to declare the array as a static field, outside Main.

Comment: I'm quite not familiar how to that. I'm sorry. How do you implement that?

Comment: Just as you passed the array to `arrayVal` so it could access the array, you also need to give acces to `Method1`. Either pass the array as an argument to the method, or declare the array as a class field so it's accessible to all the methods of the class.

Comment: @insane_developer There is no need for static variable, just parameterizing the method will do. Static variables are stateful and can do much harm.

Comment: @N.Dogac so can you reference instance fields in static methods? Sure you could change all those to non-static, but as it is, it has to be static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be your `Method1` -

```cs
static void Method1(string[] letters)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++)
        Console.Write(letters[i] + " ");    // spacing for formatting, nothing functional

    Console.WriteLine("\n\n");    // new lines for next iteration, nothing functional
}
```

and this is how you call it -

```cs
switch (choice)
{
    case 1:
        Method1(letters);
        break;
}
```

This will print *all* the user inputs that are stored by `arrayVal` method.

If you want to print any *specific* input, then -

```cs
static void Method1(string[] letters, int index)
{
    Console.Write(letters[index]);

    Console.WriteLine("\n\n");    // new lines for next iteration, nothing functional
}
```

and call it with

```cs
switch (choice)
{
    case 1:
        Method1(letters, 6);    // pass the desired index as the second argument
        break;
}
```

Hope that works for you.

**Edit :**
Since you are already passing `letters` array as a parameter to `arrayVal` method, I didn't suggest to move `letters` out of `Main` method. But you can certainly do that to make it a private field of the class. In that case, neither `arrayVal` nor `Method1` will require the `string[]` parameter in their signature.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] letters = { "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };
    int choice = 0;

    while (choice != 5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello! Enter values, then choose your action below:");
        arrayVal(letters);

        // print your array with new vales
        for (int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}. {letters[i]}");
        }

        choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        // to take a single value of array
        string indexValue = letters[choice];

        switch (choice)
        {
            //remind that the array start in position zero (0)
            case 1:    
                Method1();
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Option");
                break;
        }
    }
```

If you want get the value of array on the Method1, you have to change like this:

```
static void Method1(int i, string[] letters)
{
    Console.Write(letters[i]);
}

// and the call (in the Main)
 case 1:    
     Method1(choice, letters);
     break;
```

Comment: I really dont know why but it still says: ```The name `letters' does not exist in the current context``` in Method 1.

Comment: Oh, this is because the letters is only Main context, not the Method1.
I forgot this, but now I edit the code and updated.

Two ways for resolve:
=> Pass the letters in the Method1, like Method1(int choice, string[] letters)
OR => Declare letters like global in the class Program

Answer (score -1):

This is the idea:

```
using System;
class LabExer
{
  private static string[] letters = {"S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};

  static void arrayVal(string[] arr)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(arr[i] + ": ");
            arr[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            
        }
  }

  static void Method1(int index){
      Console.Write(letters[index]);
  }
  
  static void Main ()
  {
    int choice = 0;
    while (choice!=5)
    {
        
        Console.WriteLine("Hello! Enter values, then choose your action below:");
        arrayVal(letters);
        
        Console.WriteLine("\n1. Method 1");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Method 2");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Method 3");
        Console.WriteLine("4. Method 4");
        Console.WriteLine("5. Exit");
        
        choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                Method1(0); //your logic to decide which index
                break;
        }
    }
    
  }
}
```

You are getting the error because letters is in the scope of the Main() method. By putting it at the class level you can access it from any method in the class.

Comment: I tried printing the ```letters[i]``` but it prints nothing. Or am I doing something wrong with printing?

Comment: You have to add a parameter to the method, which would be the index of the array `static void Method1(int i){...} and then you call it with whatever index you need `Method1(0);`. My answer meant to show you how to place a static field. I did not run your code. Please read this so you understand scopes: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scope-of-variables-in-chash